# Regression Line using FIT

Tags: fitting

I'm stuck trying to figure out the regression line for a scatter plot for a set of data.

I looked at the example  given in the mathematica library.

They use a set of data with two points (x,y)

```
 data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {2, 0}};
```

Then they give the equation for the regression line

```
 line = Fit[data, {1, x}, x]
```

The problem that I'm having is based on that my set of data which is one point
per entry

```
 examplemydata = {{2},{4},{4},{6}}
```

and not hardcoded and set as X,Y as mathematica example. Mathematica automatically graphs my entries as X and the Number of the entry as Y so in essence it graphs my data as

```
 {2,1}{4,2}{4,3}{6,4}
```

but the FIT function does not automatically assume that.

Any suggestions? Im not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: check [Fit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html); you need to input `Fit[data, {1, x}, x]` where data is something like `{2,4,4,6}` (not `{{2},{4},{4},{6}}`)

Comment: on a relevant note, `Fit` interprets eg `{2,4,4,6}` as `{{1,2},{2,4},{3,4},{4,6}}` *not* as `{{2,1},{4,2},{4,3},{6,4}` (the x-coordinate goes first) same goes for `ListPlot` (see [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html?q=ListPlot)